# Random memcache calls take extra-ordinarily long

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached

Please see this appstats log, randomly some memcache calls take extraordinarily longer than others.  These are all get calls for memcached counters so there is absolutely nothing different about the calls that are taking longer than others.  Any explanation?

[image]

Comment: Can you find out the size the of the data returned by these calls? Is it much large for the slow one?

Comment: No, they are all requests for memcached counters.  So the size is always a single int value.  In fact, each time a different call takes longer than others.

Comment: What client are you using? Is it possible that the extra time you are seeing isn't happening on the server? For example, if your using java it may be a result of context switching and garbage collection.

Comment: i tagged the question python :)

Comment: are the long gets always in the same place?

Comment: they are roughly in the same place but not exactly.. so after 20 or so gets, one get would take over 300 ms.  If i do 100 gets, i would see 5 long gets almost equally apart but not exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Memcache like all GAE service is done using a remote procedure call and the response time is not generated. If the machine/network is busy it might lag.

The real question here is way are you calling memcache 20 times in a single request?
There are two ways go work around it:

1. Use the [get_multi](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/clientclass.html#Client_get_multi) to retreive all the values at once (if possible)
2. Use [the async memcache](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/clientclass.html#Client_get_multi_async), start retrving the values but don't wait for them use them when they are all ready.